# How to propagate validation to CustomField sub Components

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin23

I have a simple CustomComponent with Person being an simple data class with two string TextFields: name and sname.

This is the class:

```
data class Person(var name:String, var birth:LocalDate)

class PersonField : CustomField<Person>(){

    private val nameField:TextField
    private val birthField:DatePicker

    init {
        nameField = TextField().apply {
            placeholder = "Name"

            addValueChangeListener{updateValue()}
        }

        birthField = DatePicker().apply {
            placeholder = "Birth"

            addValueChangeListener{updateValue()}
        }

        add(nameField, birthField)
        setWidthFull()
    }

    override fun setPresentationValue(person: Person?) {
        if (person != null) {
            nameField?.value = person.name
            birthField?.value = person.birth
        }
    }

    override fun generateModelValue(): Person {
        return Person(nameField.value, birthField.value)
    }
}
```

And this is the binder where I use two validators:

```
binder.forField(personField)
            .withValidator({ value ->
                value?.name?.isNotEmpty() ?: false || value?.name?.isNotEmpty() ?: false
            }, "Name is Required")
            .withValidator({ value ->
                value.birth.isBefore(LocalDate.now())
            }, "Birth must be before today")
            .bind({person->person}, {person,field-> person.name=field.name;person.birth=field.birth})
```

Validation works correctly but I'd like to highligh the specific field that generated the error. Instead it only gives me the error message:

[image]

How could I make the "Name" subfield to turn red-ish whe the proper validator fires?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to move the binder inside your `CustomField` and bind to the internal `TextField` data `DateField`. Additionally when you do so, you can implement `DefaultValidator` inside your custom field. Something like:

> ```
> @Override
> public Validator<LocalDate> getDefaultValidator() {
>     return (value, context) -> { 
>         if (binder.isValid()) {
>             return ValidationResult.ok();
>         } else {
>             return ValidationResult.error("Person is not valid");
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

This will chain inner and outer binders, if you bind PersonField in a form using another binder there.

Comment: Thank you. It worked as expected!